# Не создаются папки с помощью скрипта PHP

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
    $unzippedDirectory = '/' . date('H:i:s');
        if (!is_dir($unzippedDirectory)) {              
            mkdir($unzippedDirectory);                              
            chmod($unzippedDirectory,0775);
        }
```

Он должен создавать папку. Все папки над ним имеют права 0775.
При вызове mkdir() никакой ошибки не выдает, но папка реально не создается.
В начале скрипта есть директива:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: По-моему нельзя создавать папки, в именах которых содержится двоеточие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обратите внимание, что директория создается в корне /
вероятно у вас нет прав на создания в корневой директории системы или директории, разрешенной в виртуалхосте веб сервера.

скорее всего веб сервер видит корень системы, но прав у него нет.
+ проверьте date.timezone в php.ini

Comment: насчет двоеточия не совсем так.
создавать такие директории можно :)

Comment: У php по дефолту нет прав записывать в корень (да и не нужно ни в коем случае). Про запретные символы читайте тут: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Имя_файла (необходимо ещё учитывать особенности файловой системы)

Comment: папка не в корне, адрес такой: "../../import/history/2013/03/05/15:44:00"

Comment: по вашему коду она проверяется и создается в корне... у вас в начале имени стоит '/' что указывает на КОРЕНЬ системы.

Answer (score 0):

уверены, что у пользователя, под которым это выполняется есть права на эту папку? и еще

> **Замечание:** Когда опция safe mode включена, PHP проверяет, имеет ли каталог, с которым вы собираетесь работать, такой же UID (владельца), как и выполняемый скрипт.

ну и на счет двоеточия верное замечание.

Comment: опция safe mode отключена

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно создать директорию относительно текущей директории - тогда нужно делать вот так

```
$unzippedDirectory = './' . date('H:i:s');
```